# load a pretrained model pytorch - dict object has no attribute eval

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

```
def save_checkpoint(state, is_best, filename='checkpoint.pth.tar'):
    torch.save(state, filename)
    if is_best:
        shutil.copyfile(filename, 'model_best.pth.tar')


save_checkpoint({
                'epoch': epoch + 1,
                'arch': args.arch,
                'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                'best_prec1': best_prec1,
                'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()
            }, is_best)
```

I am saving my model like this. How can I load back the model so that I can use it in other places, like cnn visualization?

This is how I am loading the model now:

```
torch.load('model_best.pth.tar')
```

But when I do this, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'

What am I missing here???

EDIT: I want to use the model that I trained to visualize the filters and grads. I am using this [repo](https://github.com/utkuozbulak/pytorch-cnn-visualizations/blob/master/src/misc_functions.py#L179) to make the vis. I replaced line 179 with `torch.load('model_best.pth.tar')`

Comment: I didn't get an error when i save like yours. what is your pytorch version?

Comment: @SalihKaragoz  pytorch version: 0.4.1

Comment: does it have to do something with the way I store the model? my custom dict?

Comment: I think you should give more information. There is no syntax error. Are you trying to load for multigpus or something like that?

Comment: No, no. Just trying to load model, so that I can test that and then I want to visualize the grads and filters.

Comment: @SalihKaragoz I updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, It is very hard to find the problem. last one question, when you load model within a single python script, do you get any problems?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your question :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177907/discussion-between-salih-karagoz-and-nirvair).

Answer (score 5):

First, you have stated your model.
And torch.load() gives you a dictionary. That dictionary has not an eval function. So you should upload the weights to your model.

```
import torch
from modelfolder import yourmodel

model = yourmodel()
checkpoint = torch.load('model_best.pth.tar')
try:
    checkpoint.eval()
except AttributeError as error:
    print error
### 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'

model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
### now you can evaluate it
model.eval()
```

Comment: after this i got a error:'Missing key(s) in state_dict: "fc.weight", "fc.bias". '

Answer (score -2):

`**net.eval() AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'**`

I am trying to run this command:
`sudo python3 train.py`

But I'm getting the following error:

```
2023-07-11 12:09:29,168   INFO  Loading KITTI dataset
2023-07-11 12:09:29,237   INFO  Total samples for KITTI dataset: 3769
./logs/1.pt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval.py", line 138, in <module>
    eval(net, val_data, logf, log_path, epoch, cfg, eval_set, logger)
  File "eval.py", line 54, in eval
    net.eval()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34670565)